# How do I do division with reduce function?

Tags: javascript, reduce

So I am trying to divide a list of number and here is the code for it.

```
var myArray = document.getElementById("listInput").value.split(" ");
```

I took the value from the box "listInput" and I split it so it's easier to divide. Then:

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i+=1){
if(myArray[i] === "divide")
```

Up here I made a for loop so the program would go through each splitted word until it finds the string "divide." After that:

```
{
document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value =         
myArray.reduce(function(total, curr) { 
   if (!isNaN(Number(curr))) {
     total = Number(curr) /total  ;
   }
   return total;
 }, 1);
 }
 }
 }
```

Up in this code, the box where I want to show the result "resultNumberTotal", I made it equal to a ".reduce function" as u can. I recently learnt .reduce is a good way to add/multiply/divide so. I have 2 parameters. The program goes through the loop, finds a number(curr) then finds the command "divide" then finds another number called "total and evaluated the answer for example:

[9 divide 3] = 9/3 = 3  or [1 divide 10] = 1/10 = 1

What am I doing wrong. Plz help me understand as well Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure reduce is the right tool for the job. Did you think of using regular expressions? Can you give more examples of what the input and output should be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by regular expression. And for the examples, I mean like if I put a number then I put "divide" and then I put a 2nd number I want the first number to get divided by the 2nd number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses a regular expression to extract the different parts of the calculation from the string in the input element.
One of the things it extracts is the operation which needs to be done and our function uses this value to perform the calculation and return the result.

I'm not sure this is exactly what you need, but I think this is one way to solve your problem.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("listInput");
const output = document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal");

const regex = /(\d+)\s+(divide|add|multiply|subtract)\s+(\d+)/g;

input.onchange = function(ev) {
  output.value = check(input.value);
}

function check(str) {
  let m = regex.exec(str);

  if (m == null || m.length < 4) {
    return ''
  }

  const a = m[1],
    b = m[3],
    op = m[2];
  let res = NaN;
  switch (op) {
    case 'divide':
      res = a / b;
      break;
    case 'add':
      res = a + b;
      break;
    case 'multiply':
      res = a * b;
      break;
    case 'subtract':
      res = a - b;
      break;
  }

  return '[' + a + ' ' + op + ' ' + b + '] = ' + res

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listInput" />
<input type="text" id="resultNumberTotal" />
```